# How to escape a dot in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, escaping

The values of the array $rf contain a dot:

```
  $rf = array(img34563.jpg , img34536.jpg);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM $appin_table WHERE img IN ( ".implode( ',' , $rf )."";
  $result = mysql_query($query)
  or die(mysql_error());
```

How could I escape the dot, is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are the contents of the array - string or numeric?  What's the data type of the `img` column?

Comment: Maybe a stupid response, but are you sure you don't mean `$rf = array("img34563.jpg" , "img34536.jpg");`?

Comment: The values come from a post variable containing the type of values I wrote down here, I tried to add the double quotes but that didn't help.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: See array.. If I remove the WHERE condition in the query it does print out everything that's in my db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping the dot alone won't help you; you'll end up with a query like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE img IN(img34563.jpg , img34536.jpg)
```

You'll have to apply quotes before:

```
function quote($k)
   {
      return '"' . mysql_real_escape_string($k) . '"';
   }

$values = array_map('quote', $rf);
$query = "SELECT * FROM $appin_table WHERE img IN ( ".implode( ',' , $values )."";
```

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'jpg,1292426006.jpg,1292426169.jpg,1292426916.jpg' at line 1

Comment: Hm. I know why you got that error. The last line said `implode(',', $rf)` but it should have been `implode(',', $values)`. I edited

Comment: Thanks, it's working! There is a ')' missing in the code above though, between the last two double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid escaping, use a prepared statement:

```
$rf = array('img34563.jpg', 'img34536.jpg');

$db_connection = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
$statement = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM $appin_table WHERE img IN (?,?)");
$statement->bind_param("ss", $rf[0], $rf[1]);
$statement->execute();
```

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: always use prepared statements if possible

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why are prepared statements better than escapades?

Comment: @Ben: Prepared statements are very helpful in avoiding SQL injections, as it separates the SQL statement from the actual values.